# Change color of the grid in other page with data-binding xaml UWP

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp

I have in a UWP application one grid in MainPage and in BlankPage1 another grid, I would like, at the same time, to change the color of grid in MainPage and grid in BlankPage1 with data-binding.

The code.

Color class:

```cs
class ColorGridClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SolidColorBrush _coloreGenerale = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 16, 111, 151));
    public SolidColorBrush ColoreGenerale
    {
        get => _coloreGenerale;
        set
        {
            _coloreGenerale = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ColoreGenerale)));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

MainPage xaml:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:ColorGridClass x:Name="ColorOfGrid" ColoreGenerale="Aquamarine"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Button x:Name="btnChangeColor" Content="Change Color" Click="btnChangeColor_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Foreground="{Binding }" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Grid Background="{Binding ColoreGenerale, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" Margin="10,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500">
        <TextBlock Text="Grid One" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30,30,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
    <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="532,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="1060" Width="1378"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage xaml.cs:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
}

private void btnChangeColor_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ColorOfGrid.ColoreGenerale = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```

BlankPage1 xaml:

```
<Grid Background="LightSalmon">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:ColorGridClass x:Name="ColorOfGrid" ColoreGenerale="Aquamarine"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <TextBlock Text="Page1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30,30,0,0"/>
    <Grid Background="{Binding ColoreGenerale, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="500" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="500">
        <TextBlock Text="Grid Two" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30,30,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

How can I change the color of the second grid using databinding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could very well acheive this using a StaticResource or ThemeResource

Comment: how can you give me an example?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references. This should get you started

Comment: I've seen examples but use a resource that can not change. how can I make it dynamic?

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by `use a resource that can not change`?

Comment: I badly explained myself.
I would need a small example ... I can not apply what I read to my case.

Comment: See my answer on how to use `Application.Resources` and achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case where you want to maintain consistency across the App, you can use `Application.Resources` and create a `SolidColorBrush` and use that to Bind the color/change the color wherever required.

In App.xaml create Application.Resources and add a `SolidColorBrush` that you want to use as a default `Background`. In My case i want to use `Red`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridColorSolidBrush" Color="Red" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Now change your `Mainpage.xaml` and `BlankPage.xaml` Grid `Background` to this Resource `Key`. Like below.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource GridColorSolidBrush}">
```

Now in your Button.Tapped event you can change the colour like below.

```
(Application.Current.Resources["GridColorSolidBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Green;
```

That will change the color of all `FrameworkElements` (which in this case `Grid`).

[Here](https://github.com/avknaidu/SO46240149) you can find a simple GitHub Repo.

Below is the output from my sample program.

[image]